# Firefox on kubuntu downloads icons

Tags: firefox, kubuntu

I have recently installed kubuntu alongside Arch with Kde and decided to use Firefox as my default browser because I'm not very fond of rekonq.

Some time after I installed it I realized that my downloads did not have icons and Firefox sometimes had trouble opening them appropriately.

Is this a bug or some misconfiguration? If it's the latter, how can I solve it?

Here's picture illustrating the icon issue:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue. Previous versions of Ubuntu included a `firefox-kde-support` package that allowed Firefox to use KDE's file dialogs, open-with settings, etc.. But the maintainer quit, and [the package was removed from Ubuntu 12.04](https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+bug/949949). It falls back to Firefox's built-in application chooser, [which is useless garbage](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/+bug/18995).

See also: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=140751

Comment: I don't believe it's a firefox bug judging by the age of the report and the face that it works in Arch. It seems to be a packaging bug on ubuntu's side. I partially solved it by installing the `blue-shell` ppa, which now maintains `firefox-kde-support` and I now have proper mime-type support and native dialogs but still no icons.

Comment: @vitiv: The Firefox bug is that Mozilla doesn't provide KDE support, which forces distributions to do it themselves. In Ubuntu's case, they gave up.